# Mouse wheel scrolls Chrome's page, even when in a textbox - why?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, mouse

Is there a way to stop Google Chrome from scrolling the whole page when I roll my mouse wheel in a textbox?

What I mean is if I'm writing something in a long, scrolling textbox (like the one I'm using right now) the mouse wheel scrolls the textbox if it has scrollbars and there is more text to see. This is good, this is expected.

What isn't expected is that when I've scrolled to the end of the textbox (or it doesn't have scrollbars) and keep rolling my mouse wheel, the whole screen then scrolls.

Can I turn that off somehow?

Comment: I'm wondering if a user-script could be written to perform this.

Comment: Discussed here, with possible scripts http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/36556/should-scrolling-in-a-textbox-overflow-to-scrolling-a-page , but there doesn't seem to be a general "fix" to the browser behaviour. I looked in Chrome://flags too.